# Inline functions in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the most performant way to avoid an inline function in a loop:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const handler = (idx) => console.log(idx);
  return (<>
    [...Array(100)].map((_, index) => (
      <div onClick=(() => handler(index))>Click me {index}</div>
    </>);
}
```

Guess this is a bit overengineering

```
const OtherComp = ({ index, onClick, children }) => {
  const handle = () => { onClick(index); }
  return <div onClick={handle}>{children}<div/>
} 

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const handler = useCallback((idx) => console.log(idx), []);
  return (<>
    [...Array(100)].map((_, index) => (
      <OtherComp onClick=(handler)>Click me {index}</div>
    </>);
}
```

The "issues" I was thinking about were/are:

- garbage collector (almost don't care)
- creation of the "same" function in a loop
- re-rendering of all children each for each click as the input prop has changed - let's say that click is changing the selected div

Comment: Using React, I would even create a new component, say called SomeComponentItem, for something as small as your example it might seem overkill, but if things grow it will pay dividends in the long run, index could also then be a prop..

Comment: Keith - did you mean about the impl from the update section?

Comment: I removed the "elegant" from your question, as that is off-topic on Stack Overflow without defining, objectively, what "elegance" is.

Comment: Yes, didn't see the overengineering version, the advantage is that state can now be stored with with the sub-component, and this has real benefits on component rerender.

Comment: The overengineering version  wasn't there when you posted the comment - HM removed the Updated title

Comment: Added useCallback to actually keep the same reference to handler fn

Comment: `useCallback` is missing dependency array so a new callback is created each render cycle. The array mapping is also missing the React key, which also helps with rendering performance.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you Drew

Answer (score 0):

I think that's perfectly fine. It's exceedingly unlikely to have any performance impact at all. But if it's something you're concerned about, since the `index` is scoped inside the `.map` callback, the only other option I can think of is for the handler to examine its surrounding DOM to get the index:

```
<div onClick={handler}>Click me {index}</div>
```

```
const handler = (e) => {
  const div = e.currentTarget;
  const index = [...div.parentElement.children].indexOf(div);
  console.log(index);
};
```

But using `{() => handler(index)}` is a much more React-ish style, and is a lot easier to read and make sense of - I'd prefer using that instead in all cases whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `handler` isn't too complicated, you could as well define it inside the `map`, and then refer to it directly in the `onClick`. To me personally, that even makes it clearer what is going to happen, because I don't have to make the mental jump from one function to the next to find that out.

*Working demo:*

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    [...Array(100)].map((_, index) => {
      const handler = () => console.log(index);
      return <div onClick={handler}>Click me {index}</div>;
    })
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeComponent />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

*PS - I had to make some small changes because your code was not syntactically correct.*